# What does Lambda Expression Return if Predicate returns true

Tags: c#

I am confused if the parameter `fruit` (which I know is an input parameter) is returned if the condition is true for predicate. As the following piece of code signifies:

```
List<string> fruits = new List<string> {
    "apple",
    "passionfruit",
    "banana",
    "mango",
    "orange",
    "blueberry",
    "grape",
    "strawberry"
};

IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Length < 8);
// query contains: {apple,banana,mango,orange,grape}

IEnumerable<string> query2 = query.Where(fruit => fruits.Contains("apple"));

foreach (string fruity in query2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruity);
}

// finally returns: {apple,banana,mango,orange,grape}
```

Therefore it seems as if input is returned if condition is true.

Kindly guide me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, if the predicate returns true for an element, that element will be in the subset of the elements returned by where. It will return any string from your array with length smaller than 8.

Comment: Do you expect to see only apple in the second query ?

Comment: It's simply a typo there...it should be `IEnumerable<string> query2 = query.Where(fruit => fruit.Contains("apple"));` I guess

Comment: btw; the lambda expression ***is*** the predicate: they are one-and-the-same. So if the predicate returns true, the lambda expression is *by definition* also returning true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Where` returns a filtered sequence of the input for which the predicate returned `true`. It is applied to each element in turn, and that item is either yielded or discarded. Basically:

```
public static IEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(var el in source) {
        if(predicate(el) {
            yield return el;
        }
    }
}
```

Look at the names:

```
IEnumerable<string> query2 = query.Where(fruit => fruits.Contains("apple"));
```

That says, for every `fruit`, see if the **entire set** (`fruits`, note the final `s`) returns an apple. The list `fruits` *does* contain `apple`, so that is true for every fruit.

You possibly meant:

```
IEnumerable<string> query2 = query.Where(fruit => fruit.Contains("apple"));
```

Comment: SO this is why it returns fruit(an input parameter) as the condition is true. Now as we look into the below code:

Comment: @Sadiq it applies the predicate on a per-item basis; it will yield a sequence of all the things from the input sequence for which the predicate was true. Which is why the first test returns a sequence that yields the fruits with short names. The second test is true for *all* the items, because the predicate itself does not even look at which item it is: it will always be either all-true or all-false.

Comment: delegate int anonymousDel(int i);
            anonymousDel myDelegate = new anonymousDel(
            delegate(int x)
            {
                return x * 2;
            });

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", myDelegate(5)); anonymousDel myDelegate = x => x * 2; IT does not return the input parameter in this case

Comment: @Sadiq not sure what your point is there... the example **here** doesn't return the input parameter either. It *looks* like it does, because the typo in your predicate means it returns true each time, which is to say: it filters nothing. If it is still unclear, I think it would help if you said exactly what you are *expecting* to see (and why)... Also: in the comment in your example, you're not using it as a predicate/filter...

Answer (score 1):

LINQ Where returns an IEnumerably set with all items that the predicate returns true for.

In your second query you're doing `fruits.Contains("apple")`, which is basically always true, or always false. Perhaps you meant to do the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> query2 = query.Where(fruit => fruit == "apple");
//returns: {apple}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of .Where lambda as SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM IEnumerable WHERE Predicate = TRUE;
```

For me this is preferable way due to SQL background :)